# Angular : How can i define toaster in factory and call it in Controller

Tags: angularjs

here is my **Factory** :

```
myApp.factory('newBranchRequestFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var newBranchRequestFactory = {};
    var urlBase = '/api/MyAPI/';
    newBranchRequestFactory.SaveRequester = function (requester) {

        $http.post('/api/MyAPI/SaveRequester', requester);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('newBranchRequestController', ['$scope', 'newBranchRequestFactory', function ($scope, newBranchRequestFactory, toaster) {

 $scope.SaveRequester = function (  Requester )
    {

        newBranchRequestFactory.SaveRequester(Requester);
        toaster.pop('success', "title", "text");
    }  
}
```

how can i show toaster after run SaveRequester function ?

Comment: 'toaster' is not in the array of injected values for the controller.

Comment: i didn't get you, i've added in my function ($scope, newBranchRequestFactory, toaster)

Comment: You are using the verbose injection model of an array. Either just use the function definition such as .controller('name', function(inject1, inject2){}) or in the array add 'toaster' as well as in the function definition.

Comment: ok, i did that as i said in above comment , sry for missunderstanding.
i get this error in console :toaster is not defined

Comment: oK, that worked, write it in answer section @Enzey :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the verbose injection model of an array but the number of injected params from the array does not match the number of params of your function.

Either just use the function definition such as

```
.controller('name', function(inject1, inject2){})
```

or in the array add 'toaster' to match your controller function params.